# Product page layout is not working for simple product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, product-view, simple-product

I am using Magento 2.2.3
I have created customtheme in this theme I have created below layout file for product detail page:

> app/design/frontend/My_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!--
    /**
  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
 -->
 <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
</head>
<update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
<update handle="page_calendar"/>
<body>

    <attribute name="itemtype" value="http://schema.org/Product" />
    <attribute name="itemscope" value="itemscope"/>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Catalog::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
            <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">

         <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.social" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/social.phtml" after="product.info.main">
            <!--<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/image.phtml" after="product.info.type">-->
        <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
            <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price">
                <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                    <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                    <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                    <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/image.phtml" before="-">


            <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" />
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <!-- Custom file added -->
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.custom" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_attributes.phtml"/>
        </container>


        <!--<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="custom.tab" template="product/view/docs.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Docs and FAQ</argument>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>-->


        <!-- Custom -->
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.overview" after="product.info.media" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/overview.phtml"/>

       <!-- <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details"  after="product.info.media" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description"  group="detailed_info" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="description.tab" as="description" template="product/view/description.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                 <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
                 </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="docs.tab" as="docs" template="product/view/docs.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                 <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Docs and FAQ</argument>
                 </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="customers.tab" as="customers" template="product/view/happy_customers.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                 <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Happy Customers</argument>
                 </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="parts.tab" as="parts" template="product/view/parts.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                 <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Parts</argument>
                 </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>-->

        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

         <container name="product.informations" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="detail-center">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.information" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/info.phtml"  after="product.info.media"/>
        </container>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons.additional"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block
                class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Ui\ProductViewCounter"
                name="product_viewed_counter"
                template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/counter.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>


    <move element="product.info" destination="content" before="page.main.title" />
     <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true"/>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.main" remove="true"/>
      <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true"/>






</body>
```

This layout is working fine for downloadable products but not for simple products and other types as well.

So What should I do to get it working for simple products too?

Comment: what actually you want to do to override catalog_product_view.xml layout file?

Comment: I just want this layout to work for all types of product that's all. right now it is only working for downloadable product.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Is some other layout loaded? The page is blank?

Comment: @Sigismund yes half portion of detail page is blank for simple products and other types of products. While for downloadable products detail page is working fine

Comment: I cannot show any screenshots due to copyright issues.

Comment: In that case, check `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log` if there are any warnings or errors related to template/layouts files. If that doesn't help, try enabling `Template Path Hints` and follow blocks from there. It could be just a bug in a block.